# How can I get a div content in php which not have class and id

Tags: php, html, css

I have a div in php(string) and I want to get the content.

for example --

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
      <div>
       bla bla bla
      </div>
      bla bla          
</div>
```

and i want --

```
<div>
     bla bla bla
</div>
     bla bla
```

I don't no div id or class

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Why in the world you would like to do this with PHP?

Comment: @Dai I want to get data under this div for some uses.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I want to get data under this div for some uses.

Comment: You dont know div, id or class, but you know PHP?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task you can use [regular extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

Useful functions:

```
preg_filter — Perform a regular expression search and replace
preg_grep — Return array entries that match the pattern
preg_last_error — Returns the error code of the last PCRE regex execution
preg_match_all — Perform a global regular expression match
preg_match — Perform a regular expression match
preg_quote — Quote regular expression characters
preg_replace_callback — Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback
preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace
preg_split — Split string by a regular expression
```